# Regex to strip out everything but words and numbers (and latin chars)

Tags: php, regex, punctuation

Im trying to clean a post string used in an ajax request (sanitize before db query) to allow only alphanumeric characters, spaces (1 per word, not multiple), can contain "-", and latin characters like "ç" and "é" without success, can anyone help or point me on the right direction?

This is the regex I'm using so far:

```
$string = preg_replace('/^[a-z0-9 àáâãäåçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõöøùúû-]+$/', '', mb_strtolower(utf8_encode($_POST['q'])));
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$string = mb_strtolower(utf8_encode($_POST['q'])));
$string = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9 àáâãäåçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõöøùúû-]+/g', '', $string);
$string = preg_replace('/ +/g', ' ', $string);
```

Why not just use mysql_real_escape_string?

Comment: Hi, thank you, this one worked fine, just changed the delimiters

     $string = mb_strtolower($this->input->post('q'));
            $string = preg_replace('%/[^a-z0-9 àáâãäåçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõöøùúû-]+/g%', '', $string);
            $string = preg_replace('%/ +/g%', ' ', $string);

I'm not using mysql_real_escape_string because I'm using codeigniter so everything gets escaped on framework, but that was irrelevant for this matter. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

```
$regEx = '/^[^\w\p{L}-]+$/iu';
```

`\w` - matches alphanumerics

`\p{L}` - matches a single Unicode Code Point in the 'Letters' category (see the **Unicode Categories** section [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html)).

`-` at the end of the character class matches a single hyphen.

`^` in the character classes negates the character class, so that the regex will match the opposite of the character class (anything you do *not* specify).

`+` outside of the character class says match 1 or more characters

`^` and `$` outside of the character class will cause the engine to only accept matches that start at the beginning of a line and goes until the end of the line.

After the pattern, the `i` modifier says ignore case and the `u` tells the pattern matching engine that we're going to be sending UTF8 data it's way, and `g` modifier originally present has been removed since it's not necessary in PHP (instead global matching is dependent on which matching function is called)

Comment: Hi, have not tested this one but it looks REALLY confusing to me as I'm still learning how to use regexs :) thanks anyway!!

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9 àáâãäåçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõöøùúû\-]/u', '', mb_strtolower(utf8_encode($_POST['q']), 'UTF-8'));
$string = preg_replace( '/ +/', ' ', $string );
```

should do the trick. Note that

- the character class is negated by putting ^ *inside* the character class
- you need the *u* flag when dealing with unicode strings either in the pattern or in the subject
- it's better to specify the character set explicitly in mb_* functions because otherwise they will fall back on your system defaults, and that may not be UTF-8.
- the hyphen character needed escaping (\- instead of - at the end of your character class)